# How emit objectNameChanged signal under Qt by the QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I have this code:

```
QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(d->m_object); 
w->setObjectName("test");
```

it's can not emit objectNameChanged signal, so I want to manual emit signal,
`w->objectNameChanged("test",QWidget::QPrivateSignal));` but report error `QWidget::QPrivateSignal  is private)`. How can I emit QWidget::objectNameChanged() signals?

Comment: There is no `objectNameChanged` signal

Comment: There is - in Qt 5 - but it has other signature: `void  objectNameChanged(const QString & objectName)`. Proof: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#objectName-prop

Comment: The signal should be emitted when the name is changed, why are you trying to manually emit it?

Comment: I'm areadly test w->setObjectName("somename"), but can't receive signal inside w object. this w QWidget has a Custom widget for the Qt Designer,

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation (5.7):

> Note: This is a private signal. It can be used in signal connections
>   but cannot be emitted by the user.

Anyway, the signal should be emitted, when you change the name, there should be a mistake somewhere else.